# E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)

Tags: android, video

```
 String fileName = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/oryx1001";
 MediaController videoMediaController = new MediaController(this);
 //mVideoView.setVideoPath( Uri.parse());
 mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(fileName));

 mVideoView.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
     @Override
     public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {      
       return true;
     }
 });

 videoMediaController.setVisibility(View.GONE);
 videoMediaController.setMediaPlayer(mVideoView);
 mVideoView.setMediaController(videoMediaController);
 mVideoView.requestFocus();

 mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
     //Close the progress bar and play the video
      public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
           mVideoView.start();
      }
 });

 mVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
   public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
   //jump();
   //System.out.println("dksadalkdakldsadlkadklsad");
   mp.reset();
   String fileName = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/oryx1001";
   MediaController videoMediaController = new MediaController(MainActivity.this);
   mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(fileName));
   mVideoView.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
           return true;
        }
   });

   videoMediaController.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   videoMediaController.setMediaPlayer(mVideoView);
   mVideoView.setMediaController(videoMediaController);
   mVideoView.requestFocus();
   mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        // Close the progress bar and play the video
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mVideoView.start();
        }
    });
  }
 });
```

simply my code 3gp file not working.  it works on android oreo but not on lolipop device or samsung s6. is it api thing, or device thing for codecs supported? i tried everything mp4, 3gp nothin working.
 E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)
D/VideoView: Error: -38,0
/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-38)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `mediaPlayer.start()` in the `onPrepared` method by using a listener. You are getting this error because you are calling `mediaPlayer.start()` before it has reached the prepared state.

You have set `setOnPreparedListener`

```
mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    // Close the progress bar and play the video
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mVideoView.start();
    }
});
```

but you start wrong object `mVideoView.start();` you should call

```
 mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    // Close the progress bar and play the video
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.start();//Change is hare ..
    }
});
```